# extract string with grep -oP

Tags: regex, jenkins, grep, sudo

I got empty String in variable `IMAGE_TAG` when trying to extract a substring `:R8A144` from string:
Loaded image: `rcsmw-ee:R8A144`
by `grep -oP` in Jenkins execute shell:

Here is the code:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null eccd@${DIRECTOR_IP_NUM} '
LOADED_IMAGE=$(sudo su root -c "docker load -i rcsmw-ee-5940688.4.tar")
IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $LOADED_IMAGE | grep -oP '\(:[A-ZA]\)\w+')
echo $IMAGE_TAG
'
```

here is the output:

```
bash: command substitution: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: command substitution: line 5: `echo $LOADED_IMAGE | grep -oP (:[A-ZA])w+)'
Error parsing reference: "rcsmw-ee:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

Comment: `IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $LOADED_IMAGE | grep -oP '(:[A-ZA])\w+')` works well on my bash. The error seems to be jenkins specific. What are you trying to do with this tag?

Comment: I need to get the R8A144 then create a new specific tag.

Comment: You can give a try to awk as well. IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $LOADED_IMAGE | awk -F':' '{print $2}')

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Try `IMAGE_TAG=$(echo "$LOADED_IMAGE" | grep -oP -m 1 ":[A-Z]\w*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a whole set of commands inside single quotes, so you cannot use single quotes around the `grep` pattern.

Also, the `"$LOADED_IMAGE"` is also better used in double quotes since it may cause trouble if it contains whitespaces.

Besides, the `A` after `A-Z` is redundant, as is the capturing group, you may remove the parentheses in the pattern and use

```
IMAGE_TAG=$(echo "$LOADED_IMAGE" | grep -oP -m 1 ":[A-Z]\w*")
```

Or, using an equivalent POSIX BRE regex:

```
IMAGE_TAG=$(echo "$LOADED_IMAGE" | grep -o -m 1 ":[[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]*")
```

Note `-m 1` with `grep` will extract the first match only, which seems to be what you are after here.

Comment: I don't think the backslash in `":[A-Z]\w*"` will make it through to grep . . .

Comment: @ruakh [It did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074111/extract-string-with-grep-op/58074721#comment102544321_58074111)

Comment: One reasonably convenient way to include a single-quote inside single-quotes is `'"'"'` (which ends the single-quotes, adds a double-quoted string containing just `'`, and starts a new set of single-quotes).

Comment: IMAGE_TAG=$(echo "$LOADED_IMAGE" | grep -oP -m 1 ":[A-Z]\w*")
works. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right -- per https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes, "Within double quotes, backslashes [...] preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified."

Comment: Ok, added a POSIX BRE equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use ssh with a tag as below:
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null eccd@${DIRECTOR_IP_NUM} <<'SSHTAG'
.
IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $LOADED_IMAGE | grep -oP '(:[A-ZA])\w+')
.
.
SSHTAG